# Including a header from a parent directory

Tags: makefile, header-files

I have a situation where I am given a link to source directory which goes under the parent dir. The contents of the link cannot be modified. The link has a header and .c file. The header file includes a "Config.h" file. The Config.h can only reside in the parent dir because I cannot modify anything under the link. I have to use the sources in the link and compile the parent dir. Here is the directory structure.

```
ParentDir
    |-TestSrc.c
    |-TestSrc.h
    |-Config.h
    |-Makefile
    |-LinkToSrcDir
           |-Src.c
           |-Src.h(#include "Config.h")
```

My makefile is very straightforward

```
CC = gcc
INC_DIR = -IParentDir -IParentDir/LinkToSrcDir
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra $(INC_DIR)

all: mybin
mybin: TestSrc.o Src.o
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o TestSrc.o Src.o
TestSrc.o: TestSrc.c
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c TestSrc.c
--- similar code for Src.o ----
Phony: clean (all the usual rm -f)
```

My problem is, since I cannot modify src.h, the make always complains that Config.h is not found(tried a few different ways). How do I write the Makefile to make src.h look for Config.h in parent dir?

Comment: When asking questions like this please include (via cut and paste, not paraphrase and not screenshot and not a link to some other pastebin site) the exact command that make invoked and the exact error messages you received.

Comment: @MadScientist, there is no cut and paste here. This is real code but for the last two lines, if that is what you are referring to. I accept your comment on providing full code in the future. And I just assumed Makefile always gets called by a make command, so didnt explicitly mention it. But I understand where you are coming from.

Comment: I mean, you say here "make always complains that Config.h is not found"; I recommend you include in your question the actual compile line that make printed when it ran (not the makefile recipe) and the actual error message you got, rather than paraphrase it like this.  Often the exact compile line and the exact wording of the error makes a difference.

Comment: Will do the next time.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a fully-qualified path for the compiler flags:

```
INC_DIR = -I$(CURDIR)/ParentDir -I$(CURDIR)/ParentDir/LinkToSrcDir
```

Just to be clear, when the compiler searches for header files using a relative path it always starts with the directory the source file appears in.  It doesn't start with the working directory where the compiler is invoked.

From [the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) for example:

> the preprocessor looks for header files included ... first relative to the directory of the current file

In your case, the *current file* is `LinkToSrcDir/Src.h` so all paths will be expanded relative to the directory `LinkToSrcDir`.

When you say *a link* above I assume you mean a *symbolic* link.  In that case you may not be able to use something like `-I..` because that will give you the parent of the directory linked to.

You pretty much have no alternative but to use a fully-qualified path in your `-I` options.

Comment: The makefile is in the current directory and thats why I did INC_DIR = -IParentDir -IParentDir/LinkToSrcDir

Comment: I know it's in the current directory... that's clear from your question.  I don't understand your comment.  Did you try my suggestion and it didn't work?  Or did you not understand my suggestion?

Comment: NM, i misunderstood. I now understand that you are referring to adding the absolute path and that works. I just have to figure out if that solution will work with the rest of my project. Thanks